# Are there any plans for a Standard type-erasing container?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

The process of integrating **boost** functionality into the standard library has become apparent over the years.

It seems though, that a **useful & practical** part of boost, that is **containers that provide type erasure**, has escaped this process.

1. Are there any particular reasons (performance penalty, lack of robustness) for this ?
2. Are there any **proposals** related to incorporating such functionality (eg `boost::any`) in the next Standard Library ?
3. `shared_pointer` uses type erasure, **are there any other facilities in today's Standard Library** where we can take advantage of this technique ?

Comment: "**integrating** **boost** **functionality** **into** **the** **standard** **library**" - this is the reason boost was created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Type erasure usually introduces an additional indirection and eventually virtual function calls which degrade performance.
2. There is a just recently updated working draft "C++ Extensions for Library Fundamentals" which proposes (among other features) [`boost::any` for the standard](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/n4023/fundamentals-ts.html#any).
3. `std::function` would be another example.

Comment: There are also proposals floating out there to allow a `struct` to be used as a type erasure template: however robust reflection might let us do this in a library (foreach marked method in type, write type erasure code sort of thing).  Probably not reflection 1.0 ;)

Comment: @Yakk would you mind linking the proposal you talk about here? Thanks.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Oh god, that was 3 years ago.  I would have no idea where I saw it now.  Sorry.  If I was to think about doing it in 7-10 years from now, I'd hope that the reflection proposal would get in, and the proposal for metaclasses; then, a metaclass of name type_erasure could be written to generate the required code mayhap; `type_erasure bob { int foo;  void print(std::ostream&)const; }`.  This is a much more "clean" way to do it than what I described in the above comment.

Comment: @Yakk no problem I was just curious, I didn't remember reading that particular proposal :)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I remember seeing something with a struct and some tool that runs over it.  I don't know if it was a proposal proposal or just someone talking about proposing it, or if it was just a fever dream of a younger self.

Answer (score 2):

Boost.Any made it into C++17 as [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) with a few differences.  Along with other useful types constructors: [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) and [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).